# Woocommerce Custom Shipping Zone Method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've spended last few hours trying to resolve the proper way to achieve solution for creating a custom Shipping Zone Method.

WC: 7.2.2
WP: 6.0.3

Site Health is ok, no permission errors etc. (only updates available info)

I used few information sources like:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#shipping-zone-methods

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Shipping-Method-API#properties

https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/3b37b9cc19a774665f31

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098

And many other.

Basicly i need to sample code to create (plugin) for shipping zone method with custom shipping cost function. We base od Woocommerce Easy Booking and we have number of days in meta, thtats why we can't use one of the woocommerce official premium plugins to handle that.

I've  ended up with code below:

```
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
function your_shipping_method_init()
{
    if (!class_exists('WC_Your_Shipping_Method')) {
        class WC_Your_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method
        {
            /**
             * Constructor for your shipping class
             *
             * @access public
             * @return void
             */
            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->id                 = 'diet_day_shipping'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
                $this->method_title       = __('Shipping per diet day');  // Title shown in admin
                $this->method_description = __('Shipping cost per booking'); // Description shown in admin
                $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
                //$this->title              = "Easy Booking Shipping per day"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.
                //$this->rates              = array('calculate_shipping');
                $this->supports              = array(
                    'shipping-zones',
                    'instance-settings',
                    'instance-settings-modal',
                );
                $this->instance_form_fields =
                    array(
                        'title' => array(
                            'title'         => __('Method Title'),
                            'type'             => 'text',
                            'description'     => __('This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.'),
                            'default'        => __('Daily delivery for Your diet'),
                        ),
                        'cost' => array(
                            'title'         => __('Cost'),
                            'type'             => 'number',
                            'description'     => __('This controls the cost per day.'),
                            'default'        => 7,
                        )
                    );
                $this->init();
                    $this->title                = $this->get_option('title');
                    $this->cost                = $this->get_option('cost');
                
                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
            }

            /**
             * Init your settings
             *
             * @access public
             * @return void
             */
            function init()
            {
                // Load the settings API
                $this->init_form_fields();

                // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
            }

            function init_form_fields()
            {
                $this->form_fields = array(
                    'title' => array(
                        'title'         => __('Method Title'),
                        'type'             => 'text',
                        'description'     => __('This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.'),
                        'default'        => __('Daily diet shipping cost'),
                    ),
                    'cost' => array(
                        'title'         => __('Cost'),
                        'type'             => 'number',
                        'description'     => __('This controls the cost per day.'),
                        'default'        => 7,
                    )
                );
            }

            /**
             * calculate_shipping function.
             * @param array $package (default: array())
             */
            public function calculate_shipping($package = array())
            {

                //hardcode for testing
                $shipping_number = 7;

                //probably way to calculate final shipping cost 
                /*
                foreach ($package['contents'] as $item_id => $values) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    $shipping_number = $shipping_number + $_product->wceb_get_product_booking_duration() * $values['quantity'];
                }*/

                $this->add_rate(array(
                    'id'    => $this->id . $this->instance_id,
                    'label' => 'Dostawa poza Wa-wa',
                    'cost'  => $shipping_number,
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_shipping_init', 'your_shipping_method_init');

function add_your_shipping_method($methods)
{
    $methods['diet_day_shipping'] = 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method';
    return $methods;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_your_shipping_method');
```

I need to have 2 settings (it can be only in zone, method, no need global) Title (to display for customers) and cost – to know value to multiplay days by.

I want to “Edit” button show below method on shipping zone method where i can set theese values.

Can someone help fix my code ?

For now it shows no settings options in admin panel. Not in shipping zone method row, and no in sgipping settings panel.

Also when i ser postal code from zone with my custom shipping method - cart says that there are no availble shipping methods to that postal code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also spent three hours yesterday and one today trying to figure out a very similar issue. I believe I now have a solution, or at least something that might help you to get into the right direction. The official WooCommerce documentation seems to be rather poor on the differentiation between *settings* and *instance settings* (or I couldn't find one regarding instance settings - more on that in the following paragraph).

The following is based on what I discovered so far by trial and error. If anyone has any "official" documentation on this, I'm looking forward to comments on this reply.

It is important to differentiate between "settings" and "instance settings". See this image for a visual comparison in the WooCommerce backend:

[Image showing the difference between settings and instance settings in the WC shipping settings backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KNVY.png)

**Settings**

Settings refer to "global shipping method settings", i.e., they appear in the  global submenu, but not inside of a shipping zone. The official WooCommerce documentation shows how to use settings, and how to add a new settings page:

https://woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/

https://woocommerce.com/document/settings-api/

To use the settings-functionality/API, you must specify

```
$this->supports = array('settings'); // You may also need to include shipping-zones
```

in your constructor.

"Settings" are applied/used/stored globally, i.e. irrespective of the individual shipping region.

**Instance settings**

Instance settings are settings that can be saved individually per shipping zone. To use those, you must use

```
$this->supports = array('shipping-zones', 'instance-settings', 'instance-settings-modal');
```

in your constructor.

Here is an example that made me understand the subtle but important differences for the instance settings API:

https://gist.github.com/malkafly/57a5e07fd03d6fd5cab84c6182d84c86

**Code differences and regarding your original problem**

Note that there are subtle differences regarding the exact functions and properties regarding both of the APIs. In your concrete case, you should decide for either one of the APIs, and then use the respective API in a stringent way. You are mixing up the two APIs, and this is likely why you cannot get your custom shipping method to work.

If you wish to use the (global) settings API:

- $this->supports = array('shipping-zones', 'settings');
- Use $this->form_fields (not $this->instance_form_fields)
- Use $this->settings['title'] to retrieve saved settings

If you wish to use the (shipping zone specific) instance settings API:

- Make sure your constructor looks like this/includes the following code:

  ```
      public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {
            $this->instance_id = absint( $instance_id );
            //...
      }
  ```
- Use $this->instance_settings['title'] to retrieve saved settings

**The links I posted above in the respective settings/instance settings categories contain great additional (working) code examples for each of the approaches.**